# PHP Personality Quiz

Tags: php

I'm creating a website with php where you'll be grouped into different classes by taking a personality quiz, I don't really know how to explain over text so I'll show an example below.

**Question 1: Do you like food?**
    (+) Heck yeah! (this one has the value of a)
    () EW, no.    (this one has the value of b)
**Question 2: Do you eat spiders?**
    (+) YEP.       (this one has the value of a)
    () NO.        (this one has the value of b)

(Obviously these aren't real questions, just test)
Now lets say the user chooses more questions that fit to personality a and they end with 7 a's and 3 b's. How would I go about using this info to show the personality they get?

My first thought was to add together all of the values they got (in this case 7 a's, 3 b's) then choose the personality that corresponds with the value a using an IF statement, but to do that would I use the PHP Count function?

If someone could point me in the right direction to go about this it would would be very appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do - are there sub questions? Does Q.1 depend on if Q.2 is relevant. Are you setting questions to all have a positive a) answer and negative b) answer. Can there be more than two answers (if not use YES/NO)

Comment: Yeah, there's gonna be way more than 2 questions. The questions are not directly connected to the others, and there will be 5 different personalities so I will have 5 options for each question.

Comment: I assumed more that two questions (would not be much of a quiz) but my thought was "Do you eat?" It would then be stupid to ask "Do you eat fish" = stupid example I know, but Q1 excludes Q2

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wasn't very clear with my questions. Pretty much all I need is an easy way to add the total values of all the answers and the  value (a, b, c, d, or e) that has the has the highest amount of answers is the one the user is placed in to. This is harder to explain over text than I thought haha.

Comment: How about like the magazine quiz'es - a) = 1 point b) = 2 points etc

Comment: My friend and I tried out a few scenarios with that first and we found lots of ways where answering some questions one way and some another would mess up the results. We figured using this system would be the best way to go about it. Thanks for your suggestions though!

Answer (score 1):

assuming you count how many a's and b's are in your resulting array (from your form?), you could use IF statements like this

```
<?php 
   // once your count is set...
   if ($counta < $countb) {echo "<img src='/personalitya.jpg' />";}
   elseif ($counta > $countb) {echo "<img src='personalityb.jpg' />";}
?>
```

or you could do more specific results and set

```
if ($counta == 7) {echo "<img src='/personality7.jpg' />";}
if ($counta == 6) {echo "<img src='/personality6.jpg' />";}
```

etc...
I think that's what you're looking for...if I understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store your answers in an array,

1st use array filter to get the total numbers of a's and b's
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Then you can use count() function to count how many a's and b's are there.

EDIT: posted a wrong link.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But, I am more familiar with using count, could I use an IF condition and do something like `if($question1 == "$answer.1"){ $personality1 = "$personality1 +1;"}elseif($question1 == "$answer.2"){ $personality2 = "personality2 +1";}`

Then could I select from somehow choose the highest number? And sorry if some of the code is wrong, kind of just winged it.

Comment: Oops, it should be $question1 == "answer.1" and same for the other.

Comment: What I'm going to do is set the possible answers as values then use conditional statements to detect what answer they chose, then with that I will add +1 to each score and at the end get the highest variable integer and say that is the one that they are. 

(Reading over this it is pretty unclear but it's too late to rewrite it in a readable way. If anyone else has this problem wants help go to my website www.my.iheff.net, register an account and send a message to Austin)

Thanks to those who gave suggestions.

Comment: u do know that php-count() function can only count arrays right?